# driving a Peltier with a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, lipo, mosfet-driver, peltier

I am attempting to drive a Peltier device using a single MOSFET, controlled by a microcontroller.

I am working with several different peltiers and various MOSFETs, so wont provide component details at the moment, but would like to understand if the general setup is suitable.

I am simply putting a MOSFET in series with the Peltier, and setting the Vgs of the MOSFET to significantly beyond the Vgs(th), the MOSFETs im using claim that this should put their Rds(on) to ~50-100mOhm. At the battery voltage (I'm using a single cell Lipo) of ~3.7v, the Peltier should be trying to take ~2.5A.

Instead of the expected current draw, I am seeing a significantly lower current, ~1.2A, and I seem to be getting a relatively high voltage drop across the MOSFET, as high as 0.85V.

I've ordered some relays and solid state relays, but would like to understand why the system is behaving this way, and if there is a better way to drive a Peltier than this. I am not PWMing the MOSFET, it remains on for several seconds.

Also, sometimes when the MOSFET is powered up, the microcontroller (which is using the same battery) browns out, however I am not observing a noticable voltage drop on my scope, and the uC is heavily decoupled.

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You have to provide more information: the part number of MOSFET and details on its driver circuit: how many volts do you apply to its gate?

Comment: What is the voltage on the gate of MOSFET (when turned ON). On which gate voltage that \$ R_{ds(on)} \$ is declared? 5V, 10V?

Comment: As for the microcontroller problem - what is its input DC voltage (by its specs)? What is the voltage across Li Polymer battery when uC browns out?